# Authorization with cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise, controller, cancan

Im trying to authorize each user so that they can create, read, update and destroy ONLY their own logg. I created the logg using a scaffold. I have used devise and admin as a boolean in users. I have a LoggsController, User model, logg model and ability.rb  I tried following the rails cast video so that I can allow all users to do this. So far, admins can do everything. But users cant do what I want them to.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user||= User.new 

    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all 
      can :create, Logg
      can :update, Logg do |logg|
        logg.try(:user) == user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My models and controller

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ROLES = %w[admin moderator author banned]

  has_many :loggs

  def role?(role)
    roles.include? role.to_s
  end
end

class Logg < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
end

class LoggsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :set_logg, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @loggs = Logg.all
    respond_with(@loggs)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@logg)
  end

  def new
    respond_with(@logg)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create 
    @logg.save
    respond_with(@logg)
  end

  def update
    @logg.update(logg_params)
    respond_with(@logg)
  end

  def destroy
    @logg.destroy
    respond_with(@logg)
  end

  private
  def set_logg
    @logg = Logg.find(params[:id])
  end

  def logg_params
    params.require(:logg).permit(:name, :date, :time, :whats_gone_well_this_week,    :whats_not_gone_well_this_week, :learnt_anything_new, :what_would_you_like_to_improve, :anything_else)
  end
end
```

View

```
<% if can? :show, @logg %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', logg %>
<% end %>
<% if can? :update, @logg %>
  | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_logg_path(logg) %>  
<% end %>
<% if can? :destroy, @logg %>
  | <%= link_to 'Destroy', logg, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what's the definition of `admin?`?

Comment: why don't you try this: replace this code in ability.rb `can :update, Logg do |logg|
logg.try(:user) == user
end` for this one `can :update, user_id: user.id`. I am assuming that user has_many loggs

Comment: I fixed the issue so that users can manage only their own loggs by adding a user_id in loggs controller and adding. else
    can :manage, Logg, :user_id => user.id but they can still view others loggs in the index page and the show, edit, destroy links are still visible. I tried the cancan way to add  <% if can? :create, Logg %>
  <%= link_to 'New Logg', new_logg_path %>
<% end %> but that doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're setting the Logg's owner (user) anywhere. In your create, you'll need something like:

```
def create
  @logg = current_user.loggs.create(logg_params)
  respond_with(@logg)
end
```